# Cancel next input prompt

Tags: python

How do I make it so that if the input is '!', it does not wait for the valueInput and immediately prints the dictionary?

```
itemInput = input()

valueInput = int(input())
while itemInput != '!':
    if itemInput in groceryDict.keys():
        groceryDict[itemInput] += valueInput
    else:
        groceryDict[itemInput] = valueInput
    itemInput = input()
    valueInput = int(input())
else:
    print(groceryDict)
```

for example, if someone is done entering their list, they would enter '!', but the dict wouldn't print as it is waiting to ask for the valueInput again, and the user would have to enter a value before the dict prints. So where would I properly put the valueInput and the itemInput prompt in my code?

Comment: Minor note: `if itemInput in groceryDict.keys():` can drop the `.keys()`; membership tests (and iteration) on a `dict` already check the keys only, so `.keys()` just makes an unnecessary wrapper on each call. In practice, I'd recommend making `groceryDict` either a `collections.defaultdict(int)` or a `collections.Counter()` so you don't need the test at all, and can just unconditionally do `groceryDict[itemInput] += valueInput`.

Answer (score 1):

You should only input a value after controlling the item name:

```
itemInput = input()

while itemInput != '!':
    valueInput = int(input())
    if itemInput in groceryDict.keys():
        groceryDict[itemInput] += valueInput
    else:
        groceryDict[itemInput] = valueInput
    itemInput = input()

print(groceryDict)
```

Or to have only one input for items:

```
itemInput = input()

while True:
    itemInput = input().strip()   # ignore leading or ending blank characters
    if itemInput == '!': break
    valueInput = int(input())
    if itemInput in groceryDict.keys():
        groceryDict[itemInput] += valueInput
    else:
        groceryDict[itemInput] = valueInput

print(groceryDict)
```

Comment: Definitely the best solution, avoids the duplication of tests and half the inputs. Minor maybe-improvement available on 3.8+ to avoid the duplicated `itemInput = input()` line is to move it to the `while` conditional (deleting the lines above the `while` and at the end of it) by using the walrus operator (`:=`) for assignment: `while (itemInput := input()) != '!':`

Comment: @ShadowRanger: still not used to the `:=` in Python ... Partly because I still heavily use Python 3.7...

Answer (score 0):

Just break

```
itemInput = input() 
valueInput = int(input())
while True:
    if itemInput in groceryDict.keys():
        groceryDict[itemInput] += valueInput
    else:
        groceryDict[itemInput] = valueInput
    itemInput = input()
    if itemInput == '!':
        print(groceryDict)
        break
    valueInput = int(input())
```

Answer (score 0):

A `break` may be of help:

```
if itemInput == '!':
    print(groceryDict) 
    break
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following:

```
groceryDict = {}
while True:
  itemInput = input("Enter Item:")
  if itemInput == "!":
    break
  valueInput = int(input("Enter Value for Item:"))
  if itemInput in groceryDict.keys():
    groceryDict[itemInput] += valueInput
  else:
    groceryDict[itemInput] = valueInput

print(groceryDict)
```

The loop will contines until the if statement becomes `True` and the `break`leads to ending it.
Next place the if statement directly behind the input for the item. This way the user must no longer enter a value befor the loop ends.

And be smart to the user, tell him/her/it what to enter. ;-)